# Find the length of PC

Tags: geometry, circles

Here PE is the tangent of the two circle.
 PA = 12 ; CD/AB = 2

 Find the length of PC [Source: BDMO]
[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amzBA.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

It holds that $$ PE^2= 
\boxed{PA \cdot PD = PB \cdot PC}.$$

Taking advantage of the equality in the box, we have:

$\begin{array}[t]{l}
12\cdot (PC + CD) = (12+AB) \cdot PC\\
12 PC +12 CD  = 12 PC + AB \cdot PC\\
PC = \dfrac{12CD}{AB}=24
\end{array}$

Answer (score 1):

By power of a point, $PA \cdot PD = PE^2$ and $PB \cdot PC = PE^2$. Thus, 
$$ \frac{PB}{PA} = \frac{PD}{PC}$$
and since $PB = PA + AB$ and $PD = PC + CD$, this implies
$$ 1 + \frac{AB}{PA} = 1 + \frac{CD}{PC}.$$
Subtracting 1 from both sides and solving for $PC$ yields
$$ PC = \frac{CD \cdot PA}{AB} = 2 \cdot 12 = \boxed{24}.$$